# How to identify leaf node from multi column table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary-tree

I have a table with multiple column for category/sub-categories

[image: multi level table]

I would like to identify the rows that are leaf nodes. Leaf nodes could be on any level for instance the 11th one for dresses is a leaf node as it has no child.
How can I achieve this in MS SQL?

Comment: Does this table always have 4 `Group_` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`.  SQL Server now has a convenient function `concat_ws()` that is helpful here:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             concat_ws('->', group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4) as groups
      from <table> t
     )
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.groups like concat(t.groups, '->%')
                 );
```

This is easy enough without `concat_ws()` as well:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             concat('->' + group_1,
                    '->' + group_1,
                    '->' + group_3,
                    '->' + group_4
                   ) as groups
      from <table> t
     )
```

Note:  This uses both `concat()` and `+` because they handle `NULL` values differently.  `concat()` ignores `NULL` values, but `+` returns a `NULL` value if any argument is `NULL`.